# not able to upload file using multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I have seen many answers on this and tried almost all of it but none seems to work for me. I can print the form data as ascii chars but I don't see the file stored in the public/uploads folder as expected. I can read and render stored files on react app using API but can't upload it. I get no errors, everything works fine but no file is uploaded in the folder. I'm trying to upload a file using multer and below are the code snippets :

routes/uploads.js

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    dest : function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'public/uploads/'))
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage:storage}) ;

router.post('/upload', upload.single('mypic'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("inside upload files");
    console.log(req.body); //prints non-readable characters as I am uploading image as expected               
    console.log(req.file); //says undefined
    return res.status(204).end();
});
```

API.js (React side):

```
export const uploadFile = (payload) =>   //payload is actually formdata
  fetch(`${api}/files/upload`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        //headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },                        
        headers: {              
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
        },            
        body: payload
    }
)
.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res.status;
})
.catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing :

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
```

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't work. Its basically a FormData object. what header can we use to send such data?

Comment: Have you modified your code to this ? fetch(`${api}/files/upload`,
      {
        method: 'POST',      
        body: payload
    }

Comment: Is the key of your form-data 'mypic'?

Comment: Looks like it worked (maybe I didn't check properly the first time) but uploading folders in some different folder than expected! Do you have a working sample code to use multar effectively?

Comment: Yes. I will add here.

Answer (score 1):

Try below IT contains multiple parts:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {

            const extension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
           //you can change destination runtime
            if(file.fieldname == "covers[]")
            {
                cb(null, __dirname, '../public/uploads/cover');
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                cb(null, '../public/uploads/image');
                return;
            }

        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            //you can also change name

            cb(null, filename)
        }
    });

    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
    });
```